# a (complicated) horizontal centering of a box

Tags: css, html, centering

I need to horizontally (I don't care vertically) center three boxes (div or span, I don't care) such that the mid one is always centered and its width is the smallest needed for the text (a single word) it contains, in the following way:

with a short text (a sigle word):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                            |
| ----------------------  ----------  ---------------------- |
| |                    |  |xxxxxxxx|  |                    | |
| |                    |  |        |  |                    | |
| ----------------------  ----------  ---------------------- |
|                                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

with a long text (a single word, again):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                            |
| -----------  ------------------------------  ------------- |
| |         |  |xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|  |           | |
| |         |  |                            |  |           | |
| -----------  ------------------------------  ------------- |
|                                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible?

My last temptative is far from success (since the boxes overlap, and I don't want this):

```
<div style="position:relative;";>
<span style="display:block;width:100px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;border:1px solid red"><h1>mid_text</h1>
<span style="text-align:right;position:absolute;top:0em;left:0;display:block;width:50%;float:left;border:1px solid red">left text</span>
<span style="text-align:left;position:absolute;top:0em;left:50%;display:block;float:right;width:50%;border:1px solid red">right text</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### CSS

Add this to your CSS file:

```
body
{
    padding:20px;
}
.wrapper
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper .left,
.wrapper .center,
.wrapper .right
{
    padding:0 20px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.wrapper .left,
.wrapper .right
{
    width:50%;
    background-color:#2b88f1;
}
.wrapper .center
{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

### HTML

And this is what your HTML code should look like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left">
       left
    </div>
    <div class="center"> 
        center
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="left">
       left
    </div>
    <div class="center"> 
        ceeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeenter
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

​
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YVhLt/

Comment: Good solution but not 100%, if we took two words in center instead of ceeeeeentr i.e. insert text "center something"

Comment: You mean because of the line break? OP would need to add `white-space:nowrap;` to `.wrapper .center` then.

Comment: If IE7 support is required, use an actual HTML table rather than `display:table`, with the same basic settings.